# Writing special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am still studying, my iframe is not function as I want, can you provide some advice?

```
(function($){ function overlay($img, opts){ var floating = opts.float || 'left'; var rgba = opts.rgba || '236,240,241,0.8'; var color = opts.color || '#ffffff'; $img.wrap('

'); $wrap = $img.parent(); $wrap.css('float',floating); $overlay = $('
'); $overlay.addClass('overlay'); $overlay.css('background','rgba('+rgba+')'); $links = $('
  '); $overlay.append($links); $facebook = $('

') $facebook.html(''); $links.append($facebook); $overlay.css('height',$img.attr('height'));
      $overlay.css('width',$img.attr('width')); $links.css('margin-top', (parseFloat($img.attr('height'))/2.1)+'px'); $overlay.css('margin-top',$img.css('marginTop')); $overlay.css('margin-bottom',$img.css('marginBottom')); $overlay.css('margin-left',$img.css('marginLeft'));
      $overlay.css('margin-right',$img.css('marginRight')); $overlay.css('padding-top',$img.css('paddingTop')); $overlay.css('padding-bottom',$img.css('paddingBottom')); $overlay.css('padding-left',$img.css('paddingLeft')); $overlay.css('padding-right',$img.css('paddingRight'));
      //Add links $img.before($overlay); } $.fn.socialpic = function(opts){ var opts = opts || []; $(this).each(function(){ overlay($(this), opts); }); return this; } }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the HTML entity code for the special character you want to write. In this case, `&bullet;`

Answer (score 1):

I ready change spesial carater fungsion overlay only detect txt fungtion

```
$facebook.html('');
```